# How to make a record in mongodb refrence model

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I working on Mongoose and Express project where by I have 3 models: User, Album and Purchase. The purchase model references the user and album. I am creating a POST endpoint where by I can make a purchase and then retrieve the data as well as the user and album relations which should be populated with their data, but I am stuck.

````
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  // TODO: Define Schema
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
})
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

var albumSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  // TODO: Define Schema
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  performer: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  cost: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  }
})
var Album = mongoose.model('Album', albumSchema);

var puchaseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  // TODO: Define Schema
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Album'
  },
  album: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
})
var Purchase = mongoose.model('Purchase', puchaseSchema);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.listen(3000);

// TODO: GET /albums
app.get('/albums', (req,res) => {
  Album.find()
    .then((response) => {
      res.json({data: response})
  })
    .catch(err => {
      res.json({error: err})
  })
})
// TODO: GET /albums/:id
app.get('/albums/:id', (req,res) => {
  Album.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(response => {
      res.json({data: response})
        .catch(err => {
          res.json({Error: err})
      })
  })
})
// TODO: POST /albums
app.post('/albums', (req,res) => {
 const newPost = Album({
   title: req.body.title,
   performer: req.body.performer,
   cost: req.body.cost
 })
 newPost.save(err => {
   if(err)
     res.json({error: err})
 })
   .then(data => {
     res.json({data: data})
 })
})
// TODO: PUT /albums/:id
app.put('/albums/:id', (req,res) => {
  Album.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {new: true},
                         (err, album) =>{
    if(err) return res.status(500).send(err)
    return res.json({data: album})
  })
})
// TODO: DELETE /albums/:id
app.delete('/albums/:id', (req,res) => {
  const id = req.params.id
  Album.findById(id)
        .then(docs => {
          docs.remove()
          res.status(204)
            .json({data:docs})
  })
    })
// TODO: POST /purchases
app.post('/purchases', (req,res) => {

})```
````

Comment: You have mixed up the ref attribute for your purchaseSchema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you. **Look into mongoose's [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) method.**

```
app.post('/purchases', (req,res) => {
     const user = req.body.userId;
     const album = req.body.albumId;

     const newPurchase = new Purchase({
         user: user,
         album: album
     });

     newPurchase.save().then((purchase) => {
         Purchase.findById(purchase.id).populate('user').populate('album').then((purchaseData) => {
       return res.json({purchaseData});

        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        });

     }).catch(e => {
         console.log(e);
     });
})
```

Here's an alternative for populating after saving the document.

```
    app.post('/purchases', (req,res) => {
     const user = req.body.userId;
     const album = req.body.albumId;

     const newPurchase = new Purchase({
         user: user,
         album: album
     });

     newPurchase.save().then((purchase) => {
     Purchase.populate(purchase, [{path: 'user'}, {path: 'album'}], (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
          return res.json(e);
        }

        return res.json(data);
      });

     }).catch(e => {
         console.log(e);
     });
  }

)
```

As mentioned here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate

Comment: Change it to `id`.